# How to upgrade TurnKey Linux 12.1 to 13.0

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, distributions, turnkey

I have a Turnkey Linux 12.1 installation that I would like to upgrade to Turnkey Linux 13.0. The upgrade should transition from Squeeze 6.0.8 to Wheezy 7.x. I want to upgrade the Wheezy to utilize a variety of more up-to-date packages.

I ran the standard:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But each command ends with:

```
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I suspect I'm not accessing the repository with the distribution upgrade info. Could someone help me upgrade the Turnkey Linux distribution?

Comment: Whilst the recommended upgrade path remains usage of TKLBAM to migrate data from the old instance to a new one; since v12.0 (when TurnKey rebased on Debian Squeeze) TurnKey supports 'in place' upgrade to the next major version (just as Debian itself does). Note that this only applies to major version upgrades (e.g. v12.x -> v13.x not v12.0 -> v12.1). Directions are linked to in the first paragraph of this page from the Debian wiki: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianUpgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading like that is not really supported. Instead, they recommend that you backup your data and configurations with TKLBAM, then create a new appliance with 13.0 and then import your old data: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/appliance-upgrade

Comment: I read the first paragraph, saw `dist-upgrade` & Ubuntu under the hood, and thought an inplace upgrade was possible. I didn't read the last two paragraphs. Thanks for drawing my attention to the important part!